# tree-shaking a big object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have a very big object which is various settings combined in my project

object size is something 90KB

it has four properties mainly and then sub-properties.

something like

```
obj = {
  a: { too many sub props}
  b: { too many sub props}
  c: { too many sub props}
}

i am exporting like
export const a = obj.a 
export const b = obj.b
export const c = obj.c
```

here is issue if my program use just one property whole object is coming into bundle.

example

```
import a from './setting';
import b from '.setting';

console.log(a.onlyoneprop);
console.log(b.onlyoneprop);
```

is there is any way i can further treeshake code?

Answer (score 1):

### Data

```js
obj = {
  a: { too many sub props}
  b: { too many sub props}
  c: { too many sub props}
}

// i am exporting like
export const a = obj.a 
export const b = obj.b
export const c = obj.c
```

Here you are exporting properties as named properties [named export vs default export](https://medium.com/@etherealm/named-export-vs-default-export-in-es6-affb483a0910)

### Import

When you are importing everything from `./setting`

```js
import a from './setting';
import b from '.setting';
```

Import only required

```js
import {a,b} from './setting';
// import a and b only
```

Comment: no, i am not importing everything. I am importing only a and b object
but the issue is here a and b object itself is too big and values there are dynamic so i cant make export also for properties inside a and b
hence even if i am using just a.oneprop its taking whole code of a property